# Bottom Scroller Appearing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout

everything on my site is showing up fine except in Firefox a bottom scroll bar appears. I have looked at the css and could not find anything that would be too wide or and margins pushed to the right. Any suggestions on what to do. The website is [eagleview.it](http://eagleview.it)

Comment: ya i had to take it off...press ctrl u?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary rly? well firefox v12 does...

Comment: I can confirm for Firefox 12.

Comment: @Ana wow rly, ok maybe its just my computer....

Comment: No, I meant I see the issue for FF 12. Sorry I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing `overflow: auto` to `overflow-x: hidden` on the container should solve the issue. I did it using Firebug and it worked for me.

```
.container {
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting: `overflow-x:hidden;` on your container DIV.

This method will allow your page to continue to scroll vertically.